# Rotating button content custom button

Tags: wpf, custom-controls

I defined a custom button here:

```
<Button x:Class="Views.Controls.RefreshButton"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Views.Controls"             
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="64" 
             d:DesignWidth="64"
             Background="Transparent"
             Foreground="WhiteSmoke">

    <Controls:PackIconModern Width="40" Height="40" Kind="Refresh" Margin="0,-1.3" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5" />
    <Button.RenderTransform>
        <RotateTransform x:Name="RefreshButtonTransform" Angle="0"/>
    </Button.RenderTransform>
    <Button.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Button.Click">
            <EventTrigger.Actions>
                <BeginStoryboard>
                    <Storyboard>
                        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RefreshButtonTransform" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(RotateTransform.Angle)">
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="0" />
                            <SplineDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:1" Value="360" />
                        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger.Actions>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Button.Triggers>
</Button>
```

I implemented this button into my main view.
But this results in rotating the whole button aroung the top left corner and not the middle point of the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set [`RenderTransformOrigin`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.rendertransformorigin(v=vs.110).aspx) to middle of the `Button`

```
<Button ... RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
```

From MSDN

> RenderTransformOrigin has a somewhat nonstandard use of the Point structure value, in that the Point does not represent an absolute location in a coordinate system. Instead, values between 0 and 1 are interpreted as a factor for the range of the current element in each x,y axis. **For example, (0.5,0.5) will cause the render transform to be centered on the element**, or (1,1) would place the render transform at the bottom right corner of the element.